# Way to combine csv row values with the same id in python

Tags: python

I have a CSV file that has list of transactions

For instance,

```
Year    Name       Amount
2010    John       10
2011    John       10
2012    John       10
2011    John       10
```

I want it to be grouped by year and then sorted by ID, which has the expected output

```
Year    Name       Amount
2010    John       10
2011    John       20
2012    John       10
```

My current code is similar to this one

```
with open('user.csv', 'r', errors='ignore') as csvFile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
     for row in sorted(reader):
            output.append([row[0], row[1], row[3]])
            print("Year", row[0], "  Name:" , row[1], "Amount:", row[3])
```

Thank you

Comment: You might go with a dict and use the year as key, then check if the key exists and update the amount or create a new entry.

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
#Read csv
df = pd.read_csv("user.csv")

# Groupby and sum
df_new = df.groupby(["Year", "Name"]).agg({"Amount": "sum"}).sort_values(["Year", "Name"]).reset_index()

df_new
```

Output:

```
    Year    Name    Amount
0   2010    John    10
1   2011    John    20
2   2012    John    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a good option in this use-case. But if you need to use only the build in modules.

Use:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
with open('user.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)     #Note delimiter is `,`
    header = next(reader)            #Get header
    for row in reader:
        result[(int(row[0]), row[1])] += int(row[2])  #key = row & name, value = amount

with open(filename_1, "w", newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(header) 
    for key, Amount in sorted(result.items(),  key=lambda x: x[0][0]):  #sorted by year
        writer.writerow([*key, Amount])
```